# Should you edit an accepted answer to add your own (completely different) solution to the problem?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

While browsing for information on the CSS grid layout, I came across the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45563006/5798798 and the first line made it stand out to me:

> I've never edited an accepted answer, but felt compelled to do so in
>   this case.

After reading the answer, it became clear that a user has added their own opinion to the original answer and even added a completely different solution to it (while keeping the original - below theirs).

While I can understand that the user may have wanted others to know the accepted answer's solution was not the best practise, should this not have been better done in a comment in supplement with a subsequent answer?

Comment: It absolutely should have been done in a separate answer.  The question and answers were not Community Wiki, so it isn't exactly fair game to just add information to it.

Comment: The question was/is closed, so they _couldn't_ add their own answer, not that that is a good excuse.

Answer (score 1):

No, no answer should be edited in order to add a completely different solution to the problem. Such answers should be added as separate answers.

The concern about it being an accepted answer is completely irrelevant, and this concern probably comes from a complete misunderstanding about what the green check mark next to an answer actually means:

**Accepting the answer does NOT mean that it is the best answer!**

When a user asks a question, he or she has a specific issue to solve. Upon receiving answers, the OP *may* accept an answer, and is supposed to accept the answer that most helped the OP.

Sometimes the accepted answer is the best answer, and that's why it was the answer that helped the OP the most. However, other people with a similar issue who find the problem might in fact find another answer more *useful*. That's why votes vote on the utility of an answer. So if the OP found answer A most useful and accepted it, but the people who end up at that question and find answer B most useful, they will upvote answer B. Either quickly or overtime, if another answer is more useful to the community, if another answer is more useful in general to people, it will get upvoted. And it can even surpass the accepted answer's post score. This is the correct way voting and answers should work.

There have been questions on Meta before about changing the green checkmark to the highest voted answer, and those questions reveal the misunderstanding about the green checkmark. Some people think the green checkmark is for the best answer, but that is not necessarily true. Accepting an answer is the OP's external sign showing that that answer helped that person the most, so no one besides the OP has the right to change that.

This user probably wanted to edit in their answer to the accepted answer because they thought that the new content should be in the best answer. But the asker was never helped by the new information in this edit, so it's impossible for the asker to say that the edited in information helped them the most, so it makes absolutely no sense to add brand new information to an already accepted answer.

If this user wants to make their answer available to the community, it should be added as a separate answer because that way if the content is really as useful as he or she thinks, it will be voted on by the community to whom it is useful, and if they are right, if this answer really is the best and deserves to be on top, then it will eventually get voted into place. The site design works and is great, and trying to edit new content into existing answers is like sidestepping the great design that lets the community determine the most useful content.